# How to create an Array of colors that repeats itself dynamically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of six colors and another array of 8 items.
Is there a way to repeat the colorsArray as the number of items starting from the first color at colorsArray in the same order?

```
var colorsArray = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()];
```

the new array would look like this:

```
newColorsArrayByItemsNumber = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor()];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just add the elements on the right order to your new array

```
var colorsArray = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]
var newColorsArrayByItemsNumber:[AnyObject] = []
let itemCount = 8
for(var i=0;i<itemCount;i++) {
    newColorsArrayByItemsNumber.append(colorsArray[i % colorsArray.count])
}
print(newColorsArrayByItemsNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily repeat an colorsArray:

```
colorsArray = colorsArray + colorsArray
```

Then, you can limit result to 8 items:

```
colorsArray = Array(colorsArray[0...7])
```

Putting it all together in 1 single line of code:

```
colorsArray = Array(colorsArray + colorsArray[0...1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the numbers of elements desired by the number of elements of the original array. Next you have to append a copy of the elements to the resulting array if numberOfElements > count just append the extra elements or the remaining slice of the array.

```
let colorsArray = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

extension Array {
    func replicateUpTo(numberOfElements: UInt) -> [Element] {
        if Int(numberOfElements) < count {
            return Array(self[0..<Int(numberOfElements)])
        } else {
            var result = self
            (0..<(Int(numberOfElements)/result.count)-1).forEach({ _ in result += self})
            return result + self[0..<(Int(numberOfElements) - (Int(numberOfElements)/count) * count)]
        }
    }
}

colorsArray.replicateUpTo(8)  // "[r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 1,0, r 0,5 g 0,0 b 0,5 a 1,0, r 0,0 g 0,0 b 1,0 a 1,0, r 0,0 g 1,0 b 0,0 a 1,0, r 1,0 g 1,0 b 0,0 a 1,0, r 1,0 g 0,5 b 0,0 a 1,0, r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 1,0, r 0,5 g 0,0 b 0,5 a 1,0]"
```

Answer (score 0):

May there are some more better option but this one can help you:

```
var i = 0
repeat{
  newColorsArrayByItemsNumber.append(colorsArray[i % colorsArray.count])
  i++
}while(newColorsArrayByItemsNumber.count<8)

print(newColorsArrayByItemsNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension because this pattern keeps coming back every time I need more than one element repeated:

```
extension Array {
    init?(count: Int, repeatedValues: [Element]) {
        var arr = [Element]()
        for _ in 0...(count/repeatedValues.count) {
            arr += repeatedValues
        }
        self = Array(arr[0..<count])
    }
}

let colorsArray = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

var newColorsArray = [UIColor](count: 8, repeatedValues: colorsArray)
```